# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION BSOD error, help me please

Tags: bsod, windows-8.1

I've just updated my win 8 to 8.1 and some unknown errors appeared in my PC.
First of all, I got IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL BSOD reasoned errors, but after a few driver updates, it disappeared. Now I get DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION error, when I start gaming, after 30-45 minutes. I don't know what cause this error, i've updated near all of my drivers in my computer. I thought the drivers cause all these BSODs, but not at all. I just wanted to ask you what should I do to cancel these errors? For a "milestone", I give you my two recent dump files:

Attachments:
http://data.hu/get/7275594/010414-22843-01.dmp
http://data.hu/get/7275595/010414-23062-01.dmp

Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: What do you want us to do? Fix your PC, or OS installation? Tell you what DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION means? Upvote the question? (`;)`) Tell you what software is at fault? "I hope you can help me" is really broad. We'll almost certainly be happy to help you, but please do [edit] your question to indicate what exactly you would like to know.

Comment: sorry, for my bad english. I tried to circumscribe my error, but i don't know a lot of things about it...

Comment: Your English is quite okay, someone will come along and fix it if it bothers them enough. The important part is to try to be clear about what you want to know, so that we know what to look for. (I don't know the answer to any of this, but I do know what makes a question answerable or not. :)) It's very hard to answer something that isn't a clear, specific question; good English helps make it clear, but it isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: thank you, Michael. now it's more answerable, i hope. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by the Intel HD driver (igdkmd64.sys) which hangs and this causes [this new bugcheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj154556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which was added in WIn8.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000501, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000500, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'tcpipreg' and 'btath_lwflt.' overlap

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  SINGLE_DPC_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x133

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  d

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8017a18af7c to fffff8017a166ca0

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!KiUpdateRunTime
nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
hal!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine
nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
nt!KiInterruptDispatchLBControl
nt!KxWaitForLockOwnerShip
igdkmd64
0x0

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
igdkmd64+64b69
fffff800`02e8cb69 ??              ???

IMAGE_NAME:  igdkmd64.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_DPC_igdkmd64+64b69

    Loaded symbol image file: igdkmd64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\igdkmd64.sys
    Image name: igdkmd64.sys
    Timestamp:        Wed Dec 18 21:49:12 2013
```

Ask Samsung for new drivers, generic drivers from Intel can cause issues when they are not tested by the OEM. Also rollback the driver to an older version, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the drivers or firmware may not be compatible with the new version of Windows. Go to the control panel and check for updates. That must be it. It's quite obvious since you've just upgraded to a new OS :)

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware

Comment: i've just updated my drivers. i hope it'll work. if not, try to search another possible solutions. thanks for your answer!

Comment: Updated all the drivers, tried everything in the control panel. The problem still persist...